# How to use SUMIF in an array formula to not sum blank rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, array-formulas, sumifs

Hi I am using the following array formula to sum rows AC-AG , I would like to modify it so that it does not sum if an entire row is blank.  How would I do this using an array formula since this spreadsheet is tied to a google forum and gets updates often.

I am using this formula at the top of the column.

```
={"# Boxes of Household Items"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(AC1:AG1),ROW(AC2:AG)),ROW(AC2:AG),AC2:AG))}
```

Example Below

The Formula adds up AC through AG and puts them in AR.
I want the formula to not put a zero in AR5 since the entire row is blank

[image: Example]

Comment: If all cells are blank on that row, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: At least the new title is not All Caps.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the image above I have numbers in various cells from columns A:E, then I have a formula in cells F1:F3.

- Row 1 has numbers for all cells.
- Row 2 has numbers for some cells.
- Row 3 has no numbers.

To show the sum when all/some of the cells contain numbers, I would do:

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:E1)>0,SUM(A1:E1),"")
```

We check `IF` there is at least one number using `COUNT(A1:E1)>0`. If there is at least one number, we then show the sum using `SUM(A1:E1)` otherwise we just show nothing, which is the `""` part.

For you the formula would be this in `AR2`:

```
=IF(COUNT(AC2:AG2)>0,SUM(AC2:AG2),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, How would one apply this to an array formula, so that I do not have to have a different formula for thousands?

Comment: You can just put it in AR2 and then drag it down using the little green square in the bottom-right of the cell.

Comment: This is a spreadsheet linked to a google forum that updates often so it's not very particular to keep doing this. I am trying to find how to make this an array formula so it automatically does this when a new entry is added

Comment: Why would that need to be an array formula? If you put the formula above in every row of your table, it will automatically be added to new rows.

Comment: I've just tried it in a recreation of your workbook and it worked perfectly, but I do see that this functionality can be switched off. It is on by default and therefore the formula above will work by default. If the formula doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll explain how to turn this functionality back on.